# Assigning Objects To Groups Using Variance

Tags: r, optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

I have a set of 1945 objects, each with multiple attributes. They are all stored in a single `data.frame` named `X`. For this question, I have only a single attribute of interest, `X$b`.

What I want is to assign these objects into 240 quartets (i.e 240 groups of 4 objects each, 985 left out), in such manner that the variance inside groups is maximized. Each object can appear at most once.

Assume the groups are numbered $G_1, \dotsc, G_{240}$, my initial thought is to maximize the sum of variances, $max\{ Var(G_1) + \dotsm + Var(G_{240}) \}$. This is my target function. However, this is quite far from what I know of linear programming and/or integer programming. I thought maybe starting with a greedy algorithm approach, but my experience says it would be a bad idea.

Any ideas of how to do it? Solutions using `R` would be very welcome.

Comment: Sounds like Ward clustering?

Comment: Interesting, but isn't Ward's going for minimum of within-cluster variance?

Comment: Yes, while you are trying to *maximize* within-cluster variance, if I understood correctly. I don't know of any such methods, but maybe this will help for some further research.

Comment: If you only want to maximize the variance f all the 4-member groups, why not sort data according to $b$, and then assing memberships maximally spread out? That will be close ...